# Java Regex Handling

Tags: java, regex

Looking for a java regex function to  1 - return true if Special characters present before or after from my list of array elements

2 - Return False if any alpha characters present before and after from my list of array elements
My array elements  wordsList = {"TIN","tin"}
Input:

1-CardTIN is 1111
2-Card-TIN:2222
3-CardTINis3333
4-Card@TIN@4444
5-CardTIN@5555
6-TINis9999

Expected Output:

1-True
2-True
3-False
4-True
5-True
6-False

I have tried regex function to cover these cases

Arrays.stream(wordsList).anyMatch(word -> Pattern .compile("([^a-zA-Z0-9])" + Pattern.quote(word) +"([^a-zA-Z0-9])".matcher(string).find()

But the scenario CardTin@555 is not giving the desired result as expected

Kindly help with these case

Comment: `if (element.matches("(?i)CardTIN is \\d{4}|Card-TIN:\\d{4}|Card\\@TIN\\@\\d{4}|CardTIN\\@\\d{4}")) {`.

Comment: there are many numerous test cases given are the 5 sample scenarios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure whether your requirements can be put in regex. If at all, you are running way into specialities that will become hard to maintain.

Therefore you might be better off using a lexer/scanner combination which usually make up a complete parser. Check out [ANTLR](https://www.antlr.org/).

Answer (score 1):

You can make sure that either tin or TIN using the character classes is not present:

```
^(?![a-zA-Z0-9]*(?:TIN|tin)[a-zA-Z0-9]*$).*(?:TIN|tin).*
```

- `(?i)` Case insensitive match
- `^` Start of string
- `(?![a-zA-Z0-9]*(?:TIN|tin)[a-zA-Z0-9]*$)` Assert that TIN or tin (as it is case insensitive, it does not matter for this example) does not occur between alpha numeric chars (no special characters so to say)
- `.*(?:TIN|tin).*` Match the word in the line

You might add word boundaries `\\b(?:TIN|tin)\\b` for a more precise match.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QS4vhX/1)

Example for a single line:

```
String s = "CardTIN is 1111";
String[] wordsList = {"TIN","tin"};
String alt = "(?:" + String.join("|", wordsList) + ")";
String regex = "(?i)^(?![a-zA-Z0-9]*" + alt + "[a-zA-Z0-9]*$).*" + alt + ".*";
System.out.println(s.matches(regex));
```

Output

```
true
```

---

You can also join the list of words on `|` and then filter the list:

```
String strings[] = { "CardTIN is 1111", "Card-TIN:2222", "CardTINis3333", "Card@TIN@4444", "CardTIN@5555", "TINis9999", "test", "Card Tin is 1111" };
String[] wordsList = {"TIN","tin"};
String alt = "(?:" + String.join("|", wordsList) + ")";
String regex = "(?i)^(?![a-zA-Z0-9]*" + alt + "[a-zA-Z0-9]*$).*" + alt + ".*";
List<String> result = Arrays.stream(strings)
        .filter(word -> word.matches(regex))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

for (String res : result)
    System.out.println(res);
```

Output

```
CardTIN is 1111
Card-TIN:2222
Card@TIN@4444
CardTIN@5555
Card Tin is 1111
```

See a [Java demo](https://ideone.com/k5opvF).

Comment: The test case[ Card Tin is 1111] should also match which is failing in this expression. Also the tin and Tin are in an array list and it has many tag values it is not limited to two tag values

Comment: @dhanju Then you can make the pattern case insensitive like this https://regex101.com/r/Y0KMPe/1 and for the array with tag values, you can create an alternation like this `String alternation = "(?:" + String.join("|", wordsList) + ")";`

Comment: @dhanju Something like this https://ideone.com/k5opvF

Comment: The Scenarios are not in a list , it is consumed one by one  eg : CARDTIN is 1111 is a string it is not a part of list values

Comment: @dhanju You join the values of the `wordsList` with `|` to a grouping structure that will be part of the regex. Then you loop / filter the list of strings that you have, where one of those strings can be `CARDTIN is 1111` Did you check the [Java demo link](https://ideone.com/k5opvF) ?

Comment: Yeah i got it . but i dont have a strings[] list here . I have only one input String (i.e) Card Tin is 1111 and i should match with the regex mentioned . and if the regex passes it should return true or false

Comment: @dhanju I have updated the answer with an example for just a single line.

Comment: Tinis9999 and  CardTinis 3333 should not pass as it has alpha characters before and after tin keyword